# NDSolve Systems of nonlinear coupled first order PDEs Covergence test failure

Tags: differential-equations

The system contains three nonlinear PDE with initial and boundary conditions.

```
NDSolve[{D[H[t, x], t] + D[u[t, x], x] H[t, x] + D[H[t, x], x] u[t, x] == 0,
  - D[H[t, x], t] + D[v[t, x], x] (1 - H[t, x]) - D[H[t, x], x] v[t, x] == 0,
  D[u[t, x], t] + u[t, x] D[u[t, x], x] == D[v[t, x], t] + v[t, x] D[v[t, x],x] ,
  u[0, x] == 1, v[0, x] == 1, H[0, x] == 0.5, u[t, 1] == Cos[2 t], 
  v[t, 1] == Cos[t], H[t, 1] == 0.5 Cos[2 t]}, {u, v, H}, {t, 0,  10}, {x, 1, 10}]
```

But the error I got is shown as:

> NDSolve::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the
>   derivatives.
>
> NDSolve will try solving the system as
>   differential-algebraic equations. NDSolve::ndcf: Repeated convergence
>   test failure at t == 0.7337582610498328`; unable to continue.

So, when I try to plot one solution component `u[x,t]`

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x]], {t, 0, 0.5}, {x, 1, 10}]
```

I get empty box. Any idea?

Comment: `sol =NDSolve[...];`,`Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x]] /. sol, {t, 0, 0.5}, {x, 1, 10}]`

Comment: Nope, it does not work either..

Comment: Nope, it does not work either.. I still got "NDSolve::ndcf: Repeated convergence test failure at t == 0.7337582610498328`; unable to continue." error..

Comment: That wasn't meant to solve the error, just to allow you to plot to see what's going on.